# Icon not inline with text

Tags: html, css

Here's my HTML & CSS:

```css
.category_title {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: table;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0px;
}

.pencil_icon {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  display: table;
  right: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.title_elements {
  display: inline;
  height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="category_title">
  <div onmouseover="pencil_display(event,this);" onmouseout="pencil_out(event,this);">
    <h1 id="title" class="title_elements">Doors</h1>
    <img src="Iconos/pencil.png" alt="Pencil" class="pencil_icon">
    <img src="https://www.materialui.co/materialIcons/content/add_circle_grey_192x192.png" alt="add" id="addicon" class="title_elements">
  </div>
</div>
```

It ends up looking like this:
[image]

The "add" icon is supposed to be placed next to "Doors". Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`<h1>` is a block level element so any proceeding content in the document flow will be positioned below it, no matter how much width the `h1` takes up.

There are *a lot* of ways to position content by side by side, and many will depend on your context and the UI you're trying to achieve.

You can try setting **`display: inline-block;`** or **`float:left`** for both elements to keep them on the same line

```css
.category_title {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: table;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0px;
}

.pencil_icon {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  display: table;
  right: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.title_elements {
  display: inline;

  height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<div class="category_title">
  <div onmouseover="pencil_display(event,this);" onmouseout="pencil_out(event,this);">
    <h1 id="title" class="title_elements">Doors</h1>
    <img src="Iconos/pencil.png" alt="Pencil" class="pencil_icon">
    <img src="https://www.materialui.co/materialIcons/content/add_circle_grey_192x192.png" alt="add" id="addicon" class="title_elements">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: **P.S.** When posting questions, please try to remove unimportant information to keep the problem as simple as possible.  Yes, this involves meticulously going through every line of your code, but if you don't do it, your readers and potential answers will have to - and why should they have to do the extra leg work when you didn't put in the effort either?

Answer (score 0):

One potential way is to put the icon inside the `h1` tag
You can add visibility to the hover functions to show hide images

```js
function pencil_display(event,elem){
  document.getElementById("add").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("pencil").style.display = 'table-cell';
}

function pencil_out(event,elem){
  document.getElementById("add").style.display = 'table-cell';
  document.getElementById("pencil").style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
.category_title {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: table;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0px;
}

.pencil_icon {
  display: inline;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.title_elements {
  display: inline;
  height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="category_title">
  <div onmouseover="pencil_display(event,this);" onmouseout="pencil_out(event,this);">
    <h1 id="title" class="title_elements"><img id="pencil" src="https://www.materialui.co/materialIcons/content/create_grey_108x108.png" alt="Pencil" class="pencil_icon"/>
    <img id="add" src="https://www.materialui.co/materialIcons/content/add_circle_grey_192x192.png" alt="add" id="addicon" class="title_elements">Doors</h1>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But the first img is supposed to appear only when the mouse is over the word "Doors". If I do that then the pencil icon will appear when the mouse is over the add icon as well.

Comment: Added behaviour to the function to show hide the respective images

Answer (score 0):

```css
.category_title {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.pencil_icon {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  /* display: table; */
  right: -25px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.title_elements {
  display: inline;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#addicon {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="category_title" onmouseover="pencil_display(event,this);" onmouseout="pencil_out(event,this);">
    <h1 id="title" class="title_elements">Doors</h1>
    <img src="Iconos/pencil.png" alt="Pencil" class="pencil_icon">
  </div>
  <img src="https://www.materialui.co/materialIcons/content/add_circle_grey_192x192.png" alt="add" id="addicon" class="title_elements">
</div>
```

Comment: But I want the "pencil" image to only appear when the pointer is over the title "Doors". If I do as you say then it'll appear when it's over the "add icon" as well.

Comment: @Stackoverflowed check now

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a class for the add icon and adding this:

```
.add{
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
display: table;
right: -26px;

}
```